# Elixir macros and bind_quoted

Tags: macros, metaprogramming, elixir

I have a macro that defines a module like so.

```
defmodule Bar do
  def bar do
    IO.puts "I am #{inspect __MODULE__}"
  end
end

defmodule MacroFun do

  defmacro define_module(name) do
    quote do
      defmodule unquote(name) do
        import Bar
        def foo do
          bar
          IO.puts "I am #{inspect __MODULE__}"
        end
      end
    end
  end

end

defmodule Runner do
  require MacroFun

  def run do
    MacroFun.define_module Foo
    Foo.foo
  end

end

Runner.run
```

The output of running this is:

```
I am Bar
I am Runner.Foo
```

Which makes sense; `MacroFun.define_module` was called in `Runner.run` so the module was defined and thus nested under the `Runner` module.

But now if I change `MacroFun.define_module` to use the `:bind_quoted` option:

```
  defmacro define_module(name) do
    quote bind_quoted: [name: name] do
      defmodule name do
        import Bar
        def foo do
          bar
          IO.puts "I am #{inspect __MODULE__}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

The output now becomes:

```
I am Bar
I am Foo
```

Why??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that's because the place *where* you are unquoting (binding) the variable `name`.

In the first case, you are unquoting the variable `name` when creating a module, thus binding the variable at that moment would require to check for context (check if the code is inside another module, for example). So, you get your current atom plus the appropriate context: `Runner.Foo`.

In the second case, you are unquoting the variable `name` before it's placed in a context, therefore its value will not change and it'll be the atom `Foo` (no context).

Comment: Wow, that's pretty subtle, but makes sense.  To recap to make sure I understand:   when `bind_quoted` is used, then `name` is unquoted _outside_ the body (`do`..`end`) of the quote.  But when `bind_quoted` is not used, then `name` is explicitly unquoted inside the quote.

Comment: Citing Heisenberg from Breaking Bad: "You're goddamn right".

Answer (score 0):

With this code you will see the correct values used to create the modules:

```
require Logger

defmodule Bar do
  def bar do
    IO.puts "I am #{inspect __MODULE__}"
  end
end

defmodule MacroFun do

  defmacro define_module(name) do
    quote do
      Logger.debug("#{inspect unquote(name)}")
      defmodule unquote(name) do
        import Bar
        Logger.debug("#{inspect unquote(name)}")
        def foo do
          bar
          IO.puts "I am #{inspect __MODULE__}"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  defmacro define_module2(name) do
    quote bind_quoted: [name: name] do
      defmodule name do
        import Bar
        Logger.debug("#{inspect name}")
        def foo do
          bar
          IO.puts "I am #{inspect __MODULE__}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule Runner do
  require MacroFun

  def run do
    MacroFun.define_module Foo
    Foo.foo
  end
  def run2 do
    MacroFun.define_module2 Foo2
    Foo2.foo
  end

end

Runner.run
Runner.run2
```

Output:

```
[warn]  Foo
[warn]  Runner.Foo
I am Bar
I am Runner.Foo

[warn]  Foo2
I am Bar
I am Foo2
```