# Sending a keyword list to a macro and using bind_quoted

Tags: metaprogramming, elixir

How does one send a keyword list to a macro and use `bind_quoted`?Here's an example:

The module with the macro:

```rb
defmodule MacroTime do

  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    quote bind_quoted: [opts: opts] do

      def from_opts do
        # Using opts here produces an undefined function error
        IO.puts(opts[:foo])
      end

    end
  end

end
```

The importing module and script:

```rb
defmodule Main do
  use MacroTime, foo: "bar"
end

Main.from_opts
```

Running this produces:
`** (CompileError) main.ex:2: undefined function opts/0`

You can try it out here: https://glot.io/snippets/eg2gg4huj3

I feel like I'm missing some simple concept about macros.

Comment: Try `unquote(opts)[:foo]`.

Comment: @Dogbert yeah that'll work without the bind quoted but really i want to use opts[:foo] in a few places in the quote block and want to avoid unquoting it multiple times and thus the `bind_quoted`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because the place you are quoting(binding) is not correct.

There's a similar question like this:
[Elixir macros and bind_quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889369/elixir-macros-and-bind-quoted)

And this is definition from the book Metaprogramming Elixir:

> bind_quoted
>
> The quote macro’s bind_quoted option passes a binding to the block,
>   ensuring that the outside bound variables are unquoted only a single
>   time.

Let's make it clearer.Take a look at this example

```
defmodule Print do

  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    IO.puts "In macro's context #{__MODULE__}"    # Macro context
    quote bind_quoted: [opts: opts] do
      IO.puts "In caller's context #{__MODULE__}" # Caller context
      IO.inspect opts

      def opts do
        IO.puts "In function definition's context"
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Compile:

```
iex(1)> defmodule Test do
...(1)> use Print, foo: "bar"
...(1)> end
In macro's context Elixir.Print
In caller's context Elixir.Test
[foo: "bar"]
{:module, Test,
 <<70, 79, 82, 49, 0, 0, 5, 24, 66, 69, 65, 77, 69, 120, 68, 99, 0, 0, 0, 127,
   131, 104, 2, 100, 0, 14, 101, 108, 105, 120, 105, 114, 95, 100, 111, 99, 115,
   95, 118, 49, 108, 0, 0, 0, 4, 104, 2, ...>>, {:opts, 0}}
iex(2)> Test.opts
In function definition's context
:ok
iex(3)>
```

To be clear when you want to **inject code** you have to use `unquote`.

What you are doing here is pass a binding variable `opts` to the quote block (**Caller context**) and you call it inside (**function definition's context**).

And to clarify definition of the context.This is from the book:

> A context is the scope of the caller’s bindings, imports, and aliases.
>   To the caller of a macro, the context is precious. It holds your view
>   of the world, and by virtue of immutability, you don’t expect your
>   variables, imports, and aliases to change out from underneath you.

Last for your intend of using `bind_quoted`.I suggest you should read **Hygiene protects the caller's context** and **Overriding Hygiene** to consider another solution to fit your purpose.

This is what i've figured out so far.Hope that help!

Comment: I can't quite wrap my head around _why_ it's not going to work though and if there is something I'm missing to make it work. :/